# Selecting the first “n” dates with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a response from an API like this

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
        "2. Symbol": "NSE:TECHM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-09-06",
        "4. Output Size": "Full size",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2019-09-06": {
            "1. open": "716.3500"
        },
        "2019-09-05": {
            "1. open": "710.0000"
        },
        "2019-09-04": {
            "1. open": "705.0000"
        },
        "2019-09-03": {
            "1. open": "698.0000"
        },
        "2019-08-30": {
            "1. open": "693.0000"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the first 3 dates from 'Time Series (Daily)' part of the response.
.slice(0,3) does not work as it contains dates.

Comment: How do you define "first 3"? Sorted by date descending?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You could iterate through the objects of `"Time Series (Daily)"` with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: you'll want to sort the Object.entries too, to whatever order you expect (there's no defined key order in an object)

Comment: Some reading... [The common misconception](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/#the-common-misconception-quot-the-order-of-javascript-properties-cannot-be-guaranteed-quot-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the keys in an object is not guaranteed.So `first three` is a relative term. You can use `Object.keys` to get keys from the `"Time Series (Daily)"` object and iterate through it to get the value

```js
let data = {
  "Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
    "2. Symbol": "NSE:TECHM",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-09-06",
    "4. Output Size": "Full size",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
  },
  "Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2019-09-06": {
      "1. open": "716.3500"
    },
    "2019-09-05": {
      "1. open": "710.0000"
    },
    "2019-09-04": {
      "1. open": "705.0000"
    },
    "2019-09-03": {
      "1. open": "698.0000"
    },
    "2019-08-30": {
      "1. open": "693.0000"
    }
  }
}

let newData = Object.keys(data["Time Series (Daily)"]);
for (let x = 0; x <= 2; x++) {
  console.log(data["Time Series (Daily)"][newData[x]])

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the order of keys within your object is not guaranteed, you can get the entries of your object stored at the key `"Time Series (Daily)"` using `Object.entries()`. You can then `.sort()` this array based on the date such that it is in descending order, and then use `.slice(0, n)` to get the first `n` items from your array. Finally you can encase all of this in `Object.fromEntries()` which will build an object from your array of entries:

```js
const data = {
  "Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
    "2. Symbol": "NSE:TECHM",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-09-06",
    "4. Output Size": "Full size",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
  },
  "Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2019-09-06": {
      "1. open": "716.3500"
    },
    "2019-09-05": {
      "1. open": "710.0000"
    },
    "2019-09-04": {
      "1. open": "705.0000"
    },
    "2019-09-03": {
      "1. open": "698.0000"
    },
    "2019-08-30": {
      "1. open": "693.0000"
    }
  }
}


const get_dates = (obj, n) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj["Time Series (Daily)"])
  .sort(([a], [b]) => new Date(b) - new Date(a))
  .slice(0, n));

const res = get_dates(data, 3);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Since the dates are in `YYYY-mm-dd` format you can sort them alphabetically and don't need a sort function.

Comment: you're right, but only using `.sort()` without the function would sort in ascending order, not descending